# Trace in Azure Cloud service

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I tried to enable trace in cloud service but it doesn't work.

I just created a new cloud service project with worker service.
Then I set log level in "all informations" in role settings.

If I execute this application on local emulator, I see trace.traceinformation message in emulator UI but there is no WAD table created in local azure storage.

How to enable persistance of trace in cloud service ?

Thanks,

Comment: I the configuration pane for your App Service there should be some configuration for that.  You're going to need to identity a storage account in the same region and configure a table / blob container to store your trace info.